# How to display.textcontent with objects

Tags: javascript

How do I iterate through an object that will be displayed on the webpage by using display.textContent.

Given that

```
var list = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
for (var property in list){
   div.textContent = (list[property])
} 
//Displays 3.  
//Div is referring to my HTML page.
```

I want to be able to display 1, but then after a button is clicked, it will than display 2, 3, etc.. How could I do that?

Comment: if you want to count ad infinitum, then you ran out of properties. the secon thing is, properties are not orderd, so no specific order is granted.

Comment: @NinaScholz Could be cyclical? And people get very hung up about the lack of ordering in the ES5 spec, [all implementations use ordering on object keys and ES6 *does* now guarantee it](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/nailing-object-property-order). I don't think that's worth worrying about these days.

Answer (score 1):

You don't store previous value of `div.textContent`, so you see only last iteration result. Try this

```
   var list = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
   div.textContent = "";
   for (var property in list){
       div.textContent = div.textContent + " " + (list[property]);
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have asked the question wrong. It was suppose to be that it displays 1 and then after a button is clicked it will display 2, 3, 4 .. so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
    var list = {x:1, y:2, z:3},
        index = 1, // Store the current iteration
        keys = Object.keys(list); // Grab all the keys for the object
    var button = document.querySelector("button"),
        div = document.querySelector("div");
    // Bind your click handler
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Might want to do something after '3'
        if(index >= keys.length) return;
        // Otherwise set the content from the key at 'index' and increment
        // the index for the next click
        div.textContent = list[keys[index++]];
    });
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<button>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to display `1,2,3` every time a button is clicked?

```js
function displayResult(){
  var list = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
  var div = document.querySelector("#myDiv"); //getting my div element

  var text = new Array();

  for (var property in list){
    text.push(list[property]) //adding values in text array
  }

  div.textContent = text.join(",") //array concatenation
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<button onclick="displayResult()">Display</button>
```